# OpenGL binding shader stages and programs confusion

Tags: opengl, shader

I am currently using shader pipeline objects in OpenGL (separable shader stages) along with the older style single programs with `glUseProgram()`. I'm wondering, in the documentation it says:

```
If there is a current program object established by `glUseProgram`, 
the bound program pipeline object has no effect on rendering or uniform updates.
```

This is confusing to me because I seem to be able to do:

```
glUseProgram(6); // Render using the single program
glBindProgramPipeline(pipeline_ID);
glUseProgramStages(pipeline_ID, GL_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT, shaderID);
glUseProgramStages(pipeline_ID, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, shaderID);
```

without first setting `glUseProgram(0)` before calling `glUseProgramPipeline`. The documentation I thought implied that it wouldn't work, but I can render fine like this. Is it necessary to set `glUseProgram(0)` before calling `glBindProgramPipeline`?

Comment: @BDL Oh I see, I didn't understand it like that. Hopefully someone can clarify.

Answer (score 2):

> has no effect on rendering or uniform updates

Nothing in the code you have shown deals with "rendering" or "uniform updates". If you call `glUniform`, it will go to program object 6, not to anything in the pipeline (unless 6 happens to be in the pipeline). If you render, you will use the shaders in program object 6, not those in the pipeline (again, unless 6 happens to be in the pipeline).

So long as there is a program in use, the pipeline will not affect rendering.

It should also be noted that `glUseProgramStages` doesn't affect `pipeline_ID` because it is bound to the context. It affects that pipeline because you pass it as a parameter. You didn't have to bind it first. Indeed, the only reason to bind a pipeline is to *render with it*; all of its state setting functions use DSA-style.

Comment: Thanks, so that binding pipeline before attaching the shader stages is unnecessary. If I'm understanding right, if shader program 6 is bound, and I attach the frag and vertex shader to the pipeline, the next call will use shader program 6. I first need to bind the pipeline. But, as my original question asked, does glUseProgram have to be set to (0) first before binding my pipeline? I'm guessing not.

Comment: @Zebrafish: Your question is like asking "do I have to set the pointer variable `A` to NULL before setting the pointer variable `B`?"

Comment: I've just been testing some stuff, I found that binding the shader pipeline is really really slow, whereas attaching the shader stages to it is nearly negligible. Binding the pipeline seems to slow my system down way more than for example texture switches, or binding VBOs even. Weird.